# cppcheck from command line not recognized

Tags: c++, cppcheck

I downloaded cppcheck to analyze my C++ programs, successfuly got to work it´s gui environment but I would also like to use it from command line.

In C:\users\me\documents\main.cpp
is my cpp program that I try to analyze with cppcheck. When I type cppcheck main.cpp in cmd, I only get a message saying 'cppcheck' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Is there anything I should link my cppcheck with in order to get recognized by command line?

Comment: the `c++` tag is for questions about c++ code

Comment: Is `cppcheck` in your `PATH`?

Comment: The directory where the cppcheck is installed needs to be in your path or you need to supply the full pathname to it.

Comment: Ok and should I add that into system variables or user variables?

Answer (score 3):

The directory where `cppcheck` is installed needs to be added to your `PATH` if not present, or in alternative you have to give the full-pathname to the execution command.